# Donor card blacklisted within webform or CiviCRM?

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm

Drupal 7.87
CiviCRM 5.41.0

We have a donor that has tried to donate and receives a reject code 55

In the logs I see the following "The CiviCRM "contribution transact" API returned the error: "Error REJECT: 55" when called by function "validate" on line 97 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc"

I have called iATSpayments and the card is not blacklisted with them. He called his card and they said it is not even getting to them. He was able to make the donation with a different card.

Is there somewhere with Webform CiviCRM Integration or within CiviCRM that I can check to see if the card is blacklisted within our system?

Answer (score 1):

REJ:55 is System Error
https://content.iatspayments.com/developers-ach-reject-codes

It could well be that the bank is not reachable at the moment. And another card (bank account) from another bank worked.

Comment: He has tried multiple times over the last week with no joy

Comment: You could comtact iATS Customer service and ask if they can see more details. Some banks will return generic system error for other account failures.

Comment: I did that before I posted here. They were the ones that thought there might be something within civi that was doing an initial blacklist check

Comment: An iATS REJ code is not generated by CiviCRM. Did you double check your Fraud tool settings in iATSpayments.com?

Comment: This is not an iATS reject. This is in my Drupal logs. iATS does not show anything for this.

Comment: It's in your logs b/c we're relaying the message (the REJECT) from iATS to your logs.